# How to create a search functionality in Flask that will be based on query parameters?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am going through Python course for web-developers and currently dealing with Flask. Recently I have got a task from my lector to create a searching functionality for endpoint "/events" with a help of query parameters. I hardly figure out what should I start with and whether I should use WTF-Forms for this case or not. More detailed code (my attempts) is being published below.

Here is my database model:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    begin_at = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    end_at = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    max_users = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, server_default="false")
```

This is a form for searching:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search_event_by_title = StringField(label="Search event by title", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label="Search", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Here is a view:

```
@app.route("/events", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def event_list():
    query = db.select(Event.id, Event.title)
    events = db.session.execute(query)
    context = {
        "events": events
    }
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        search_title = request.form.get('title')
        result = Event.query.filter_by(title=search_title).all()
        return render_template("event/list.html", result=result)
    return render_template("event/list.html", **context, form=form)
```

"/events" is displaying list of events (links) by default and I need to implement searching functionality at this page to make input in search bar filter database query and render correct output. I have truly no idea how to connect query parameters with form (if it's needed here; we can do without it also) and make querying of a database in correct way - 'events' must be searched and filtered by 'title' criteria. Current code does nothing. After making search attempt by existing title in 'Event' database, "event/list.html" this template keeps showing a full list of events, ignoring filtering.

This is html file (probably main mistakes are here):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Events list</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('event_list') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_token }}
    {{ form.search_event_by_title }}
    {{ form.submit }}
    {% for item in result%}
        {{ item.title }}
    {% endfor %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in events %}
        <li><a href="{{url_for('event_detail', id=item.id)}}">{{ item.id }}: {{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Please, help. I really need to figure it out :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use query parameters, transferring using the POST method is not necessary. The names and values of the input fields are automatically appended to the URL and can be requested on the server with `request.args` when you use GET.

I think WTForms is not optimal and necessary for this purpose.

This example shows you a simplified version of searching for titles in the events.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import (
    Integer, 
    String, 
    Text
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase, 
    Mapped, 
    mapped_column, 
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///sample.db'
)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

db = SQLAlchemy(app, model_class=Base)

class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=False)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

    events = [Event(title=f'title-{i}') for i in range(1, 11)]
    db.session.add_all(events)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    qs = request.args.get('qs', '')
    stmt = db.select(Event)
    if qs:
        stmt = stmt.where(Event.title.ilike(f'%{qs}%'))
    events = db.session.execute(stmt).scalars()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="qs" value="{{ qs }}" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <ul>
        {% for event in events -%}
        <li>{{ event.title }}</li>
        {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

You partially use the legacy query interface and the associated way to define models. The procedure still remains the same.

```py
def index():
    qs = request.args.get('qs', '')
    query = Event.query
    if qs:
        query = query.filter(Event.title.ilike(f'%{qs}%'))
    events = query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

Comment: That's really what I needed! I truly appreciate it, Sir !